# C# generic type not assignable

Tags: c#, generics

I want to write a *CommandProcessor* using generics. The idea being that a *Command* is issued via a single object (the *CommandProcessor* itself) that then identifies the *Command Handlers* that process the given command.

However, the following code doesn't compile, and I've not been able to understand why:

```
class GenericCommandProcessor : ICommandProcessor
{
    private readonly IDictionary<Type, IList<ICommandHandler<ICommand>>> _handlers = 
        new Dictionary<Type, IList<ICommandHandler<ICommand>>>();

    public void Register<TCommand>(ICommandHandler<TCommand> handler) 
        where TCommand : ICommand
    {
        IList<ICommandHandler<ICommand>> handlers = GetHandlers<TCommand>();
        handlers.Add(handler); // <-- This doesn't compile
    }

    public void Process<TCommand>(TCommand command)
        where TCommand : ICommand
    {
        IList<ICommandHandler<ICommand>> handlers = GetHandlers<TCommand>();

        foreach (var commandHandler in handlers)
        {
            commandHandler.Handle(command);
        }
    }

    private IList<ICommandHandler<ICommand>> GetHandlers<TCommand>()
    {
        Type commandType = typeof(TCommand);

        IList<ICommandHandler<ICommand>> handlers;
        if (!_handlers.TryGetValue(commandType, out handlers))
        {
            handlers = new List<ICommandHandler<ICommand>>();
            _handlers.Add(commandType, handlers);
        }
        return handlers;
    }
}
```

This is the line that doesn't compile:

```
handlers.Add(handler);
```

The compiler returns the following error:

```
cannot convert from 'GenericCommandHandlerTest.ICommandHandler<TCommand>' to 'GenericCommandHandlerTest.ICommandHandler<GenericCommandHandlerTest.ICommand>'
```

I would expect it to, because `Register()` has a generic constraint:

```
where TCommand : ICommand
```

I've avoided the issue by resolving the command handler list from IoC (Castle Windsor in my case) in favour of having the dictionary of lists of registered handlers, but I'd love to understand why, at the CLR level, this code doesn't compile. I think I just can't see the wood for the trees...

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Why make the method generic at all? T can only ever be IListItem so why bother with a generic method?

Comment: Pasted the same into VS, replaced only `IListItem` on `ICollection` because I do not have `IListItem`, it compiles successfully.

Comment: D'oh! Sorry about that - I wrote that code directly into SO.com, trying to come up with a simple example. I've now posted a more full example, and the exact compiler error. I've left out a few other classes for brevity, but I can provide them here if necessary.

Comment: It's all Jeff's fault. Why doesn't SO compile the C# code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change your method to this:

```
public void AddListItem(IListItem listItem)
{
    _items.Add(listItem);
}
```

No need to use generics here.

As others already said: Even without the change, your code compiles, so please update your sample code.

**Update** after you fixed your example:
You can't add a variable of type `ICommandHandler<TCommand>` to a `IList<ICommandHandler<ICommand>>`, because `ICommandHandler<ICommand>` and `ICommandHandler<TCommand>` are two different types, although `TCommand` implements `ICommand`. If it *would* work, my first answer would be correct again and you wouldn't need to make your method generic in the first place.

I guess [Covariance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx) would be helpful here, but unfortunately it is not supported in that case.

Comment: I do need generics in my real example. This was a fatally over-simplified example, which I've completely replaced now. Sorry for wasting your time (I foolishly wrote the original example directly into SO.com, which hasn't yet had a C# compiler implemented :))

Answer (score 3):

*Edit*

What you're looking for is, like Daniel said, covariance.

If you are using C# 4, this actually exists, but not in a helpful form for you. For this example to work, `ICommandHandler` needs to be contravariant. If TCommand was only ever an `out` parameter in `ICommandHandler` and you would define `ICommandHandler` as

```
interface ICommandHandler<out TCommand> where TCommand: ICommand { ... }
```

then you would be able to store an `ICommandHandler<TCommand>` in a `List<ICommandHandler<ICommand>>`, because an `ICommandHandler<TCommand>` can be safely cast to a `ICommandHandler<ICommand>` - we know that if something returns a `TCommand`, it returns an `ICommand`.

However, in your case, `TCommand` is an `in` parameter, and to convert an `ICommandHandler<TCommand>` to a `ICommandHandler<ICommand>` you would need to know that every `ICommand` is an `TCommand`, which is obviously not true, which is why you can't do this conversion.

Neither of the two solutions I can think of right now are pretty.

1. Make the dictionary untyped (a `IDictionary<Type, IList>`, or even a `IDictionary<Type, object>`) and cast to an `IList<ICommandHandler<TCommand>>`, which would always work because you only add a command to it when the Type key matches.
2. Make an `ICommandHandlerWrapper` that accepts an `ICommandHandler<TCommand>` as is in itself an `ICommandHandler<ICommand>`; when a method is called it does a type check and calls the underlying value.

---

*Old version*

[image: Works on my machine]
<sub>(source: [typepad.com](https://codinghorror.typepad.com/.a/6a0120a85dcdae970b0128776ff992970c-pi))</sub>

Possibly you're missing something important in your code example.

But I do want to ask, why use

```
public void AddListItem<T>(T listItem)
    where T : IListItem
{
    _items.Add(listItem);
}
```

and not

```
public void AddListItem(IListItem listItem)
{
    _items.Add(listItem);
}
```

Comment: Maybe it is simplified example. Anyway `it works on my machine` also

Comment: Yes - it was a fatally over-simplified example, which I've completely replaced now. Sorry for wasting your time (I foolishly wrote the original example directly into SO.com, which hasn't yet had a C# compiler implemented :))

Comment: @Neil: I've added another answer for you.

Comment: I don't agree with your explanation: "you would need to know that every TCommand is an ICommand, which is obviously not true". IMHO, it IS obviously true, that every TCommand is an ICommand, because of the constraint.

Comment: @Daniel: You're right. I meant to say "you would need to know that every `ICommand` is an `TCommand`". Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Fundamentally, the problem is that you're trying to mix compile-time safety with a concept which you can't express: the fact that the dictionary maps `typeof(T)` to something related to `T`. In similar cases, I've found it useful to design the *API* around compile-time safety, but keep a small bit of code which requires casting. In this case, that just needs to be the `GetHandlers()` method (which isn't thread-safe, by the way - I hope that doesn't matter).

Here's the complete class:

```
class GenericCommandProcessor : ICommandProcessor
{
    private readonly IDictionary<Type, object> _handlers = 
        new Dictionary<Type, object>();

    public void Register<TCommand>(ICommandHandler<TCommand> handler) 
        where TCommand : ICommand
    {
        IList<ICommandHandler<TCommand>> handlers = GetHandlers<TCommand>();
        handlers.Add(handler);
    }

    public void Process<TCommand>(TCommand command)
        where TCommand : ICommand
    {
        IList<ICommandHandler<TCommand>> handlers = GetHandlers<TCommand>();

        foreach (var commandHandler in handlers)
        {
            commandHandler.Handle(command);
        }
    }

    private IList<ICommandHandler<TCommand>> GetHandlers<TCommand>()
    {
        Type commandType = typeof(TCommand);

        object untypedValue;
        if (!_handlers.TryGetValue(commandType, out untypedValue))
        {
            untypedValue = new List<ICommandHandler<TCommand>>();
            _handlers.Add(commandType, untypedValue);
        }
        return (IList<ICommandHandler<TCommand>>) untypedValue;
    }
}
```

You could potentially change the `TValue` type argument of the dictionary to something more restrictive (e.g. `IList`) but it wouldn't really make much difference.

Comment: Thanks Jon - using `object` and casting was one of my possible solutions before I turned to Windsor, so it's good to see I wasn't being stupid. The really confusing thing for me really, is why that generic constraint on `Register()` wasn't enough to make it work...

Comment: @Neil: The problem was that the type of the variable `handlers` - an `IList<ICommandHandler<TCommand>>` isn't the same as an `IList<ICommandHandler<ICommand>>`, even when `TCommand` implements `ICommand` - because for the latter list, you can add *any* command-handler to the list, whereas for the former list it has to be a command handler for the specific `TCommand`. A bunch of bananas isn't a fruit-bowl - you can't add an apple to it :)

Answer (score 1):

I did the following and was able to compile.

```
public interface IListItem
{
    int MyProperty { get; set; }
} 

public class ListProvider
{
    private IList<IListItem> _items = new List<IListItem>();

    public void AddListItem<T>(T listItem) where T : IListItem
    {
        _items.Add(listItem);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Works just fine for me, too

```
class Program
{
    private static readonly IList<IListItem> _items = new List<IListItem>();

    public static void AddListItem<T>(T listItem) where T : IListItem
    {
        _items.Add(listItem);

        foreach (var item in _items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test tester = new Test();

        AddListItem(tester);
    }
}

internal interface IListItem
{
}

public class Test : IListItem
{
}
```